# Php, array printing

Tags: php, arrays

I  have an array:

```
Array ( 
  [0] => Array ( 
      [userid] => 5 
      [0] => 5 
      [firstname] => DALPA 
      [1] => DALPA 
      [lastname] => DALPA 
      [2] => DALPA 
  )
)
```

when i try to print this using foreach loop i get an error

```
<?php
include('../conn.php');

$q = $_GET['q'];
$adress = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE firstname= :q ");
$adress->bindValue(':q', $q, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$adress->execute();
$result = $adress->fetchAll();
 
foreach($result as $item){
  echo $item . "\n";

}
?>
```

Error:`Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\admin\adres\adres.php on line 13`

Been asked many times but none of them solved my problem, what should I do?

Comment: You have a multidimensional array. `$result` has only one element, at index 0, which is an array. Use `$result[0]` if you expect only one result from the query. If it can return multiple results, use nested loops.

Comment: Advice for the future: use `var_dump` instead of `print_r`. Not only does it structure the dump more nicely, it also contains additional useful information.

Comment: $len = count($result);->1 only gives the length of the first string,so how do i get the child's length

Comment: By iterating the array and doing the count on the children.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`php's` *echo* statement can only *echo* strings. If it is not a *string* but a *number* for example, it will try to converse the given value to a string. With an array that is not possible.

In your case you are looping trough an `array` containing another `array`. As the error tells you, it fails to echo an array because it expects something that can be converted to a string.

So either use

```
foreach($result as $item) {
    print_r($item) // or var_dump($item)
}
```

Or echo `key => value` pairs using

```
foreach($result as $item) {
    echo $item['firstname'] . "\n";
    echo $item['lastname'] . "\n";

    ... and so on
}
```

If you are expecting only one `item` to be returned, update your query by using [`fetch`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) instead of `fetchAll`, which will return only one row.

You can then omit the unnecessary foreach loop.

---

And if you realy want to *echo the array*, you have to do the conversion manualy by using `json_encode`, which will convert the array to an `JSON` string.

```
echo json_encode( $result );
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer is very revealing